# Internet Browsers

Tags: html, browser

I have internet explorer and Firefox and i am setting firefox as my default browser. If i open a .html or .mht file in which browser will that file open

Where in the registry the changes regarding the default browser will be made

Comment: Should this really be tagged MFC?

Comment: @moocha Sorry, didn't have enough rep to remove the tag myself.

Comment: I can't believe the close police didn't get this one yet.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733211/getting-default-browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned above, there are various ways to do this sensibly without having to go near the registry.
If however, for some reason that is currently beyond me, you absolutely *have* to do this through the registry, see if this is any help. This is specifically for html files, you'll have to infer the rest from this procedure.

1. Open regedit and navigate yourself to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\htmlfile\shell\open\command`
2. Edit the `(Default)` String to the location of the program you wish to use to open the file.
3. If you also want to change the icon goto `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\htmlfile\DefaultIcon` and change the location there.

This should work, though I also recommend you change the same keys in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\htmlfile` as windows has been known to randomly ignore bits of its registry when it so chooses.

As I say though, this is an incredibly long winded way of going about it.

Answer (score 2):

I cant tell you where in the registry the change is made but if the browser doesnt ask you whether it should be your default browser next time you open it, just check the according option in Preferences.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows XP you can change file type associations like this:

1. Open a windows explorer window.
2. Click tools -> folder options -> file types.
3. Find HTML in the list, and click change.
4. Choose the program you want to open HTML files with, and click OK.
5. Click OK again on the folder options window and you're set.