# Getting Default browser

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++, browser, mfc

How can I determine which is the default browser in my system programatically. The code must be developed using vc++ 
Is there any API for this ?

Where in the registry is the default browser value stored?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can find the default browser in the registry

i.e. for Windows XP and Vista is located at

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet\
```

Comment: Instead of this check out this

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer 
\FileExts\.html\UserChoice 

this  gives the default browser in the machine

Comment: sabbu: this does not necessarily give you the default browser only the default program for opening html files. On my machine ultraedit is the default for htmlfiles.

Comment: You can get the name of the default browser from "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet" and look up the commandline from the HKLM key

Answer (score 13):

TL;DR: If `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet\` exists read that; otherwise read `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\`.

After reading the answers here I found little concensus on how to detect the default browser so I did some experiments and research to figure it out.  I downloaded the Firefox source, wrote a script that reads a bunch of registry entries and also ran Process Explorer all while changing the default browser over and over.

I found there are a lot of registry keys that Firefox and Chrome change when each sets itself as the default browser.  I believe Safari and Opera are both similar in behavior.  IE appears to change only one of the registry keys I was watching.

What I found was that while most browsers change other registry paths, all browsers change `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet\` `(default)`

Here are the registry value from the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet\` `(default)` while each browser is the default browser.

- IE 9.0.8112.16421: `IEXPLORE.EXE`
- Chrome 21.0.1180.60 m: `Google Chrome`
- Firefox 10.0.2: `FIREFOX.EXE`
- Safari 3.2.2: `Safari.exe`
- Opera 12.01: `Opera`

Tested on Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium SP1 64-bit

Edit:

I found on a fresh install of Windows XP SP3 `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\` does not exist. In this case you should read the default browser from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\`. I suspect this is also the case on fresh installs of other versions of Windows.

Addendum:

The `ShellExecute` method is a great solution if all you want to do is open a web page in the default browser.  However, if you want to, for example, install an extension in only the default browser, `ShellExecute` does not solve the problem.

Comment: What if I don't have the Internet icon shown on my Start menu? Does this still work? The consensus seems to me to be that you don't need to know this. Just use `ShellExecute[Ex]` and specify a URL. It will handle opening the user's default browser.

Comment: Good question!  When I ran the tests I didn't have the internet icon showing in my start menu and it worked.


As for your second part, the original question was 'how to detect the default browser'.  What if you don't want to open a web page.  In my case the `ShellExecute` would not work because I want to have my plugin installer install a plugin in only the default browser.

Comment: I made a quick and convenient function to get default browser with a pure Windows API (and my custom libs): https://gist.github.com/ScienceDiscoverer/2fa53eee017e53773c1f2737138d4377

Answer (score 11):

You normally do not need to know this. `ShellExecute(0,0,"http://stackoverflow.com",0,0,SW_SHOWNORMAL);` will do the trick. Windows will spot the http:// and figure out from there that you want to open a URL. The "default" webbrowser is pretty much defined as the webbrowser used by Windows for this task.

It's not just http:// which is supported. ShellExecute can start the default webbrowser with https:// URLs as well. For mailto: URLs, it starts the default mail client.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The OP did not say he needed to launch the browser, he said he needed to know what it is. That said, `ShellExecute` is NEVER recommended as it is a security risk. I know, in your case it isn't. But generally, it's not recommended to use `ShellExecute`

Comment: `ShellExecute` will also fail to open local file links like `file:///D:/foo.com/index.html#some_part`.

Answer (score 4):

As its name suggests, `StartMenuInternet` is for registering a Web browser onto the Start Menu (and it only applies to XP and Vista, it is deprecated starting with Windows 7).  That does not necessarily establish the browser as the default browser for the entire system.  There are many different ways a browser can be registered for different purposes (loading a file, loading a URL, loading data based on a MIME type, etc).  Each of those registrations are separate.

[Default Programs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144154.aspx)

[How to Register an Internet Browser or Email Client With the Windows Start Menu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd203067.aspx)

[Registering an Application to a URL Protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914.aspx)

[File Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144148.aspx)

Personally, I would probably look at the registration of the "http" and/or "https" URL handler to determine the default browser, since that will be the app that loads when the user types a URL into the Start Menu or Windows Explorer, or an app passes a URL to `ShellExecute/Ex()`.

Answer (score 2):

Read the default value of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet` and optionally check `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\XXX\shell\open\command` where XXX is that value picked up from the first key.

Comment: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer 
\FileExts\.html\UserChoice

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to read the registry if you use [`AssocQueryString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-assocquerystringw).

```
WCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
DWORD size = _countof(szPath);

HRESULT err = AssocQueryString(
    0,
    ASSOCSTR_EXECUTABLE,
    L"http",
    NULL,
    szPath,
    &size
);
if (err != S_OK) {
    return; // Handle error
}

// szPath == "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
```