# how to get the path of an .exe file from the registry file

Tags: qt

I need to link the existing files with my qt application.what I mean is when the user clicks a push button the corresponding path of the file should be fetched from the registry and link with the button click event.I got the code for checking whether the particular file is exist or not.but dont know how to read the default path of that .exe file.Kindly send your suggestions.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you at least tell in what kind of environment your working...

Comment: i think his os is windows because he mentioned regesty...

Comment: Please always mention whether you're using Qt4 or Qt5.

Comment: Also, why do you need the path? For launching the program? You don't need the path for that, Qt provides a way of launching standard components, like the default browser or email program. Is that what you actually want?

Answer (score 0):

Use [QCoreApplication::applicationFilePath()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qcoreapplication.html#applicationFilePath) to get the currently running executable filename with full path. Or [QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qcoreapplication.html#applicationDirPath) if you want just the path without the executable filename. Not sure how the registry comes into it.

Edit: Following comments, if you want to get the path of a standard component, say the browser, do as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733211/getting-default-browser).

Look at the registry entry for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet\Default`

This will give you a key which you can use to look up: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet\(key_from_above)\shell\open\command`